# recover LUKS password centos

Tags: linux, centos, disk-encryption

I know that it may sound stupid but I forgot the encryption LUKS password(after a year of no-activity on that specific server) so I was wondering if there is any way to disable or reset this password. The OS is running as virtual machine on  on VMWARE host and I'm asked to insert the LUKS password when I start/power-up the server.
thank you in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1):

> > I did something really stupid.  I forgot my password to my encrypted
> >     filesystem.  Is there any way for me to either recover the password or
> >     mount the filesystem as root?
>
> Without the password, it's *supposed*
>   to be difficult.  Otherwise anyone
>   could just click "recover the
>   password" or mount it as root, eh?

http://www.luni.org/pipermail/luni/2008-November/025723.html

I.e. **You're probably out of luck, unless you can remember your password.**

---

If you do wish to go crazy and try to break the encryption....
http://questions.securitytube.net/questions/948/production-issue-i-forgot-my-luks-passphrase-how-can-i-bruteforce-it-or-crack-t

But even then chances are slim you could do it in a reasonable amount of time.